# How to partition with a 8GB SSD and a 16GB memory card

Tags: partitioning, ssd, sd-card

I would like to use my available memory as a single area. I have a 8GB SSD and a 16GB SD card. I also have 1GB RAM. 
I want to repartition and reinstall Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. 
I have been running into problems because of memory limitations although I store very little on the computer, usually not more than 2GB and this temporarily. 
It would be nice if I also could occasionally use another SD card in the reader to load pictures online. That would mean that I would have to briefly be able to remove the 16GB SD card to insert another one.

Answer (score 1):

Then you just have to manually copy files to the sdcard when you run low on internal space, or know it is a large file you only occasionally need access to.  If you were to combine them as a single storage unit, you could not remove the sdcard.

Comment: I tried to install the system on the 8GB SSD but somehow it's often not big enough although I don't store anything on it. It often tell me that there is no space left. I suppose the caches take a lot of space but what else? I use Opera, Firefox and Chromium as they all have problems with some websites and we are 2 users, so need 2 browsers to keep logged in each in one. Maybe I should learn to make space on the SSD when needed.

Comment: I guess I need a tutorial about how to partition the 8GB SSD and where to mount what. If only the system would be mounted on the SSD and all the temporary files, caches, home, etc. on the SD card, it might work better.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu installs a lot of things you probably don't need. 8 GB is probably not enough, my own system has 16GB already (only the system, I have seperate drives/partitions for home and swap).

I think you would be better of with a much lighter distro (Ubuntu has gained some weight over the years).

Try installing Lubuntu, I think you will need about 5GB for the system so this should work.
use zram swap (http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/increased-performance-in-linux-with.html).

it is possible to use the SD card as your home partition but beware: removing it can lead to unforseen consequences.